# Function Properties

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

The question is as follows:

- Let $f$ be a function $f : U → V$ , where $U$ and $V$ are non-empty
  sets. Prove or refute that $f$ is injective iff there is a function
  $g : V → U$ with $g ◦ f = Id_U$ .

Apparently I **cannot** assume that $g$ is injective while proving this because $U$ can be greater than $V$ which would mean that $g$ is injective.

Why can I not do this?

Also, how do I then prove this? The answer given by my TA isn't clear, neither is the one given by my professor.

Thanks in advance! :)

**Note: I've already received a grade on this/this is a past assignment question!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assume that $g$ is injective because that's an additional hypothesis to the statement.  It's like breaking the rules of the game.

Here is a proof: Suppose $g$ exists.
We want to show that
$$
f(x) = f(y) \implies x=y
$$
for all $x$ and $y$ in $U$
(this is equivalent to the definition of injective function).
Given $x$ and $y$ in $U$ with $f(x) = f(y)$, apply $g$ to both sides:
\begin{align*}
    g(f(x)) &= g(f(y)) \\
\implies \operatorname{Id}_U x &= \operatorname{Id}_U y \\
\implies x &= y
\end{align*}
So $f$ is injective.

(See if you can prove this interesting addition: $g$ must be a surjection.)

On the other hand, suppose $f$ is injective.  We have to construct $g$.  Choose an arbitrary point $u_0 \in U$.  Given $v \in V$, either $v = f(u)$ for some $u\in U$, or it isn't.  If it is, set $g(v) = u$.  If it isn't, set $g(v) = u_0$.  Since $f$ is injective, $g$ is a function (fill in the details if this isn't obvious to you). By construction, $g(f(u)) = u$ for all $u \in U$.

(Again, the $g$ constructed here must be a surjection.  Can you see why?)

Comment: I did something similar to what you showed me.
This is what I did:

$f(u) = f(v) \rightarrow u = v$  and $g(v) = g(u) \rightarrow v = u $ where I assumed already that $f$ is injective (my mistake from the beginning) and then subsituted it into the defintion of injection (to prove that it was injective).

Answer (score 0):

Let $g$ exists and $x,y\in U.$ Let $f(x)=f(y)$ this implies $g\circ f(x)=g\circ f(y).$ As $g\circ f$ is identity, therfore $x=y.$ Hence $f$ is injective.

Conversely, suppose $f$ is injective, therefore $f:U\rightarrow \text{Range of } f\subset V  $ is bijective. Therefore there is $f^{-1}:\text{Range of } f\rightarrow U.$

Define 
$g(x)=\begin{cases}
f^{-1}(x) \quad if \quad x\in \text{Range of } f\\
a\quad if \quad x\notin \text{Range of } f
\end{cases}$ 
where $a\in U$ is fixed.

Verify $g$ is well defined and satisfies the conclusion.